# DOM parser for Java prints same value

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this xml file

```
<Cdtr>
    <Nm>DEF Electronics</Nm>
    <PstlAdr>
        <AdrLine>Corn Exchange 5th Floor</AdrLine>
        <AdrLine>Mark Lane 55</AdrLine>
        <AdrLine>EC3R7NE London</AdrLine>
        <AdrLine>GB</AdrLine>
    </PstlAdr>
</Cdtr>
```

I am trying to parse the xml, get leaf tags names(which has values) and their respective values using dom parser in Java. Following is the code i am using for that.

```
public class GetNodeValues {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

   String xmlFile = "C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/sample.xml";
   File file = new File(xmlFile);
   if(file.exists()){
   // Create a factory
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   // Use the factory to create a builder
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
   // Get a list of all elements in the document
   NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
   System.out.println("XML Elements: ");


   for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
     // Get element
    Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
    String nodnam = element.getNodeName();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(nodnam);
    Element ele = (Element) nl.item(0);
    if (ele.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) // then it has text

          String val = ele.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
          if (val.startsWith("\n")) {         //Discarding pseudo nodes
          }else {
        System.out.println("Node: "+nodnam+" | Val: "+val); //print node names and values
          }
         }
   }
}
else{
   System.out.print("File not found!");
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.exit(1);
   }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following result.

```
Node: AdrLine | Val: Corn Exchange 5th Floor
Node: AdrLine | Val: Corn Exchange 5th Floor
Node: AdrLine | Val: Corn Exchange 5th Floor
Node: AdrLine | Val: Corn Exchange 5th Floor
```

Please help. I am not understanding why its repeating the tag value. The expected output is

```
Node: AdrLine | Val: Corn Exchange 5th Floor
Node: AdrLine | Val: Mark Lane 55
Node: AdrLine | Val: EC3R7NE London
Node: AdrLine | Val: GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While parsing the document, you use `Document.getElementsByTagName(String tagname)`. According to its Javadoc, it returns all `Element`s in a document **in document order**. Since your structure has multiple `AddrLine` elements, and since you always pick the zeroth element from this list, it always gives you the same element.

Instead, you might want to write something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
    String nodnam = element.getNodeName();

    if (element.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) // then it has text
    {
    // etc., etc.
```

Summarising, don't try to retrieve an element from the document when you already have it available.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply.
Sorry but after changing 0 to i the output is coming as blank.
I mean its not outputing anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer, and also tried to explain **why** it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot mthmulders, the program is working fine now. I did the changes as you suggested...Thanks again :)

Comment: Excellent, worked for me on a totally different xml issue. Much appreciated!

Comment: That is good work @mthmulders, you got it right.. just to clarify, I've posted the actual code but i don't need any votes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program recompiled to print all the elements in an xml document

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String xmlFile = "staff.xml";
        File file = new File(xmlFile);
        if (file.exists()) {
            // Create a factory
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            // Use the factory to create a builder
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // Get a list of all elements in the document
            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                // Get element
                Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
                String nodnam = element.getNodeName();
                if (element.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) {
                    String val = element.getChildNodes().item(0)
                            .getNodeValue();
                    if (!val.startsWith("\n"))
                        System.out.println(nodnam + "==" + val);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("File not found!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

There you go. It prints all the elements in the file.